# mvc post method not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm struggling with a problem and I cant find any way to solve it.

Here is my class Student :

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public int Nota { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the post method from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Student student)
{
    if (student == null) return BadRequest();
    studenti.Add(student);
    return CreatedAtRoute("StudentApi", new { ID = student.ID }, student);
}
```

I've tried sending a JSON like:

```
{ "ID": 6, "Nume": "Test", "Prenume": "TestP", "Nota": 10, "Status": true }
```

and returning it... everytime I'm getting null and no element is getting added to the list...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to format code properly... then give more details about *how* you're posting the JSON

Comment: I'm posting it using Postman, Content-Type: application/json and im sending the model mentioned above.
{ "ID": 6,
"Nume": "Test",
"Prenume": "TestP",
"Nota": 10,
"Status": true
}

Comment: Put debug point in check are you able to hit this method? If not check you route configuration.

Comment: So please put that information into the question...

Comment: Jon Skeet, sorry... I'm kind of new here.

MANISH, I've tried and I'm able to hit it.

Comment: What is `studenti` and where do you store it?

Comment: public static List<Student> studenti = new List<Student>()
with few elements added. I've stored it in the controller.

The other methods are working fine ... GET, GETID and DELETE.

Comment: And you are sure the `Controller` isn't created every time you call the service? Try to save it in the session for example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JfpKSPqb here is the code for the list and controller method POST... I've got no idea how to save it in the session, im struggling on learning .NET. the list has few more elements, but I've deleted it to save some space.

Comment: Doesnt seem to get the JSON element correctly...

Comment: Is the student null when you hit your breakpoint? I just tested this by creating a new web api project and it worked

Comment: Works for me too : https://github.com/crowcoder/Post_Student_SO38281108

Comment: I keep getting NULL when sending the POST json to add an element ... and automatically return BadRequest :/

Comment: Idk where I'm doing it wrong, I'm at the beginning with asp.net

Comment: In PostMan, hit the "generate code" link, choose "Http", and post that in your question (not comment).

Comment: Uhm, I've found the mistake... It was the configroute, mistakenly modified it... Thank you for your support, guys ! I really appreciate the members of this community !

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the problem is because you're not showing us how you call the Post action but let's say you have a web api controller called `StudentController` which looks like this:

```
public class StudentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Student student)
    {
        if (student == null) return BadRequest();
        //studenti.Add(student);
        return CreatedAtRoute("StudentApi", new { ID = student.ID }, student);
    }
}
```

To post a `Student` to the Post action using jQuery you can do this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAddStudent").click(function () {
            var student = {
                "ID": 6,
                "Nume": "Test",
                "Prenume": "TestP",
                "Nota": 10,
                "Status": true
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/Student",
                data: student,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("New student created.");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Called failed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnAddStudent" value="Add Student" />
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` is not only not required (and I would never recommend it), but is for the response, not the request.  [Did you mean `contentType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: Thank you very much, Sirs! So... is it correct using datatype or should I use contentType ?

Comment: Remove dataType completely.I tried it on my side and the call still works.And please remember to mark as answered if my post helped you